# observableArray: push to source does not update UI (foreach) of copy

Tags: knockout.js

I have an observable array that I copy to another observable array like this:

```js
var source = ko.observableArray(),
    copy = ko.observableArray();

copy(source());
source.push('a'); // 'a' is added to the copy but not to the UI (foreach)
```

when I push to source (source.push('a')) the copy will have the new item, but if I bind copy to a foreach the UI is not updated. If I push to the copy, it will update the UI (foreach).

Fiddle showing my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/GvGkp/2/

Comment: This really isn't a copy as they both ultimately point to the same underlying structure. (you could have just done `var source=copy=ko.observableArray()`  Why are you creating 2 variables that point to the same array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want both observable array "points" to the same data use

```
array2(array1);
```

In this situation the both arrays will be updated simultaneously (and UI too). Is that what you want?